# CSRF-Protector-PHP как использовать?

Tags: javascript, php, token, csrf

Нашёл на просторах интернета вот эту штуку https://owasp.org/www-project-csrfprotector/
Там есть ссылка на Гит: https://github.com/mebjas/CSRF-Protector-PHP
Автор говорит что работает в гугле, значит штука должна быть рабочая.
В общем сделал всё по инструкции:

1. установил через composer,
2. переименовал файл в config.php(читает из него настройки успешно)
3. прописал необходимые настройки и создал тестовый файл
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Ничего не работает, отправляю форму, а мне выбрасывает ошибку: "403 Access Forbidden by CSRFProtector!" (из настроек файла config.php)
   Причём в куках токен вижу что создался, но в форму нигде не добавляется и с запросом POST и GET не отправляется(var_dump($_POST) и var_dump($_GET) подтвердили - пусто)
   Вот код тестового файла:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Учитывая, что в вики написано что-то про буферизацию вывода — попробуйте перенести инициализацию библиотеки в самое начало файла, перед `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: пробовал, добавляются поля "<input type="hidden" id="csrfp_hidden_data_token" value="csrf">" и <input type="hidden" id="csrfp_hidden_data_urls" value="[]">, а перед ними почему то вставляется поле с тегами <noscript>Не работает JavaScript</noscript>, как будто отключён JS в браузере, но он включён. Пробовал так же на других браузерах, тоже самое.

Comment: Кстати скрытые теги передаются после закрывающего тега формы, соответственно они не отправляются при передачи формы

Answer (score 0):

В общем реализацию данного автора я не смог пристроить к своему проекту, по этому решил создать свою реализацию защиты csrf: https://github.com/TheCHIM/csrf